# css MIME type text/html AND AddType ignored

Tags: html, css, apache, .htaccess

Here is the problem, try to load a css file from a folder and get the console error: "Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html". Try to fix it by adding .htaccess file (in the root/in same folder as css) with "AddType text/css .css" in it, but it is completly ignored.

How can it be fix?

(Don't know if matters but I'm in windows 8.1 and WAMP)

Appreciate any feedback.

Comment: Had to add this to the .htaccess: RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f, which I stil find weird, because it was opening the file alright but in text/html

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<FilesMatch "(\.css)$">
    AddType text/css .css
    Header set Content-Type text/css
</FilesMatch>
```

But you really shouldn't have to.  `text/html` is normal.

Comment: did you put it under `<Directory /var/www/>` - but you know, wherever yours might be

Answer (score 0):

Because of a security issue it is not enough to set style sheet "rel" tag type property to text/css, you should set content type in http headers(content-type:text/css), it seems you use Apache but in case another person have this problem in IIS and see this page: go to control panel -> programs and features -> turn windows features on or off -> internet information services -> world wide web services -> common http features -> static content, enable this option and restart your IIS.